# ERB template binding not cascading to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have the following code:

```
user = "GG"
erb = ERB.new "Hi <%= user %>!"
    
puts erb.result(binding)
```

resulting in the correct `Hi GG!`

If I create a helper:

```
module Helper
  def hello
    "hello"
  end
end

include Helper

erb = ERB.new "Hi <%= hello %>!"
    
puts erb.result(binding)
```

still works and puts: `Hi hello!`

but if I use a variable from the context in the helper I get problems:

```
module Helper
  def hello
    "hello #{user}"
  end
end

include Helper

user = "GG"
erb = ERB.new "Hi <%= hello %>!"
    
puts erb.result(binding)
```

I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
```

why is this happening? how could I solve it?

Thanks.

**update**
I tried setting the variable as an instance variable:

```
module Helper
  def hello
    "hello #{@user}"
  end
end

include Helper

@user = "GG"
erb = ERB.new "Hi <%= hello %>!"
    
puts erb.result(binding)
```

this seems to work, I'm not sure what's the difference though.

also I need this to work as I'm working on the rspec test, in the rails service (in the app), the same code is working great.

Comment: Regarding your edit. Local variables just work that way in ruby. Check this guide: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/ruby-scope-binding/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with ERB. Call just `hello` instead of `ERB.new "Hi <%= hello %>!".result(binding)` to see it.

Methods don't have access to local variables not defined inside them. Turn `user` to a method or an instance_variable to access it.